# how can i make daily count of alarms which has severity either Critical or Major using groupby or resampling

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data with Eventdate and severity as major or minor. Data looks like below:-

```
INPUT:-
Eventdate                 Latest Priority
08/02/2019 12:00:00AM      Major
09/02/2019 11:00:00AM      Major
02/02/2019 12:00:00AM      Minor
04/02/2019 12:00:00AM      Critical
08/02/2019 08:00:00AM      Major
08/02/2019 08:00:00AM      Critical
```

i want to print a result with grouping it with Eventdate, and printing only those severity which has major and Critical

i am trying using resampling and groupby in pandas but failing.

i am trying using resampling and groupby but failing.

```
print(df.resample('D', on='Event Date Time - TT')['Latest Priority'].size())
```

OUTPUT:-

```
04/02/2019       Critical  1
08/02/2019       Major     2
08/02/2019       Critical  1
09/02/2019       Major     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to datetime first by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)  and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['Eventdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Eventdate'])

df1 = df[df['severity'].isin(['Major','Critical'])]

df2 = (df1.groupby([df1['Eventdate'].dt.floor('D'), 'severity'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df2)

   Eventdate  severity  count
0 2019-04-02  Critical      1
1 2019-08-02  Critical      1
2 2019-08-02     Major      2
3 2019-09-02     Major      1
```

Alternative:

```
df2 = (df1.groupby([df1['Eventdate'].dt.date, 'severity'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df2)
```

Comment: but how to get Latest Priority also printed in the solution